# OpenGL, VAOs and multiple buffers

Tags: opengl

I am writing a little graphics engine using OpenGL ( via OpenTK with C# ).

To define vertex attributes, I have a VertexDeclaration class with an array of VertexElement structures that are mapped to glEnableVertexAttribArray/glVertexAttribPointer calls.

Also, to support multiple vertex streams, I have a special structure holding a vertex buffer, vertex declaration, vertex offset and instance frequency (like the XNA's VertexBufferBinding structure).

Currently, whenever a drawing call is invoked, I iterate over all the set vertex streams and
bind their vertex buffers, apply vertex declarations, disable unused vertex attributes and draw the primitives.

I would like to use VAOs to cache the glEnableVertexAttribArray calls into them,
and whenever a vertex stream is applied, bind the VAO and change its array buffer binding.

Is that a correct usage of VAOs?

Comment: it seems [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149728/when-should-glvertexattribpointer-be-called) is a useful link here. Not sure why the answer says "No" to "caching" the `glEnableVertexAttribArray` calls. The answer to the linked question "When to call `glVertexAttribPointer`?" says that's exactly what VAOs are for and that's the recommended approach nowadays.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> Is that a correct usage of VAOs?

No<sup>1</sup>.

`glVertexAttribPointer` [uses the buffer object that was bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` **at the moment the function was called**](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object). So you can't do this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(...);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObject);
glDrawArrays(...);
```

This will *not* use `bufferObject`; it will use whatever was bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` when `glVertexAttribPointer` was originally called.

VAOs capture this state. So the VAO will, for each vertex attribute, store whatever buffer object was bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` when it was called. This allows you to do things like this:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer1);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, ...);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, ...);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, ...);
```

Attributes 0 and 1 will come from `buffer1`, and attribute 2 will come from `buffer2`. VAO now captures all of that state. To render, you just do this:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDraw*();
```

In short, if you want to change where an attribute's storage comes from in OpenGL, you must also change *it's format*. Even if it's the same format, you must call `glVertexAttribPointer` again.

<sup>1</sup>: This discussion assumes you're *not* using the new [ARB_vertex_attrib_binding](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_attrib_binding.txt). Or, as it is otherwise known, "[**Exactly how Direct3D does vertex attribute binding.**](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Separate_attribute_format)" If you happen to be using an implementation that offers this extension, you can effectively do what you're talking about, because the attribute format is not tied with the buffer object's storage. Also, the tortured logic of `glVertexAttribPointer` is gone.

In general, the way we solve this in the OpenGL world is to put as many things as possible in the same buffer object. Failing that, just use one VAO for each object.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. Then where does the `glBufferData` step come into action? Don't you have to buffer the data first before using the `glVertexAttribPointer`? Sorry I am very new to OpenGL

Comment: I know this is 10 years old, I'm just surprised that no one else has pointed out that OP was working with C#, and the code in this answer is C++.