# When should glVertexAttribPointer be called?

Tags: opengl

It's not obvious from the documentation when `glVertexAttribPointer` should be called. It looks like it's part of VBO initialisation, but I notice example code calling it during rendering.

`glVertexAttribPointer(vertexAttributeId, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex2D), reinterpret_cast<const GLvoid*>(offsetof(Vertex2D, m_x)));`

Should `glVertexAttribPointer` be called during initialisation of a `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` or should it be called during rendering (after a call to `glBindBuffer`)?

Comment: Maybe the question you should ask is *what does it do*, not when it should be called. If you know what it does, then when to call it is *obvious*. And if you think "it's part of VBO initialization", then your idea of what this function does is very wrong.

Comment: @NicolBolas It stores the offset of the attribute data (from the currently bound buffer)? And the attributeId is the location of the attribute in the shader (retrieved from `glGetAttribLocation` or set via `glBindAttribLocation`)?

Comment: "*It stores the offset of the attribute data (from the currently bound buffer)?*" [*Dangerously* incomplete.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) It also stores the buffer object to be used for that attribute (as well as [format information](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_format) and [stride data](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_buffer_offset_and_stride) for it).

Comment: What is your favourite OpenGL learning resource, by the way?

Comment: @ChristianRau I mostly read the docs on the OpenGL site. Nicol's site is excellent as well.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The function `glVertexAttribPointer` specifies the format and source buffer (ignoring the deprecated usage of client arrays) of a vertex attribute that is used when rendering something (i.e. the next `glDraw...` call).

Now there are two scenarios. You either use vertex array objects (VAOs) or you don't (though not using VAOs is deprecated and discouraged/prohibited in modern OpenGL). If you're *not* using VAOs, then you would usually call `glVertexAttribPointer` (and the corresponding `glEnableVertexAttribArray`) right before rendering to setup the state properly. If using VAOs though, you actually call it (and the enable function) inside the VAO creation code (which is usually part of some initialization or object creation), since its settings are stored inside the VAO and all you need to do when rendering is bind the VAO and call a draw function.

But no matter when you call `glVertexAttribPointer`, you should bind the corresponding buffer right before (no matter when that was actually created and filled), since the `glVertexAttribPointer` function sets the currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` as source buffer for this attribute (and stores this setting, so afterwards you can freely bind another VBO).

So in modern OpenGL using VAOs (which is recommended), it's usually similar to this workflow:

```
//initialization
glGenVertexArrays
glBindVertexArray

glGenBuffers
glBindBuffer
glBufferData

glVertexAttribPointer
glEnableVertexAttribArray

glBindVertexArray(0)

glDeleteBuffers //you can already delete it after the VAO is unbound, since the
                //VAO still references it, keeping it alive (see comments below).

...

//rendering
glBindVertexArray
glDrawWhatever
```

---

When not using VAOs it would be something like that:

```
//initialization
glGenBuffers
glBindBuffer
glBufferData

...

//rendering
glBindBuffer
glVertexAttribPointer
glEnableVertexAttribArray
glDrawWhatever
```

Comment: Take care with deleting buffers `If a buffer object that is currently bound is deleted, the binding reverts to 0 (the absence of any buffer object, which reverts to client memory usage).`

Comment: So you delete the buffer whilst the VAO is still bound? Do you need to call `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` before you delete it?

Comment: @t.niese when can I unbind the VBO / delete the VBO?

Comment: @t.niese Still no problem, because after the `glVertexAttribPointer` you can freely unbind it.

Comment: @MarkIngram The `glVertexAttribPointer` call stores the VBO used for that attribute, so after this call, you can at least unbind it. With deleting I'm not sure if you can do that without a VAO (but you should). But if a VAO is used, you can freely delete the VBO after `glVertexAttribPointer` (of course only if *you* don't need it anymore, e.g. for updating its data). It won't get deleted by the GL until it's not referenced anymore, it's just deleted from *your* point of view.

Comment: @ChristianRau that would be great if that is the case, do you have a source for that? `VAO` just stores states but no data, and i could not - does not mean that it does not exist :D - find a part in the specs that say that the Buffer an be deleted and is kept in memory while the `VAO` is _using_ it.

Comment: @t.niese The VAO doesn't store data, but it *references* data and that keeps it alive. All those `glDelete...` functions are in the end non-binding requests. They only delete things for *you*. From the top of my head the only source I can provide right now is that I have succesfully done it like so but I try to dig it up in the spec.

Comment: @t.niese Of course the previous comment only applies for the statement about freely *deleting* it. The fact the you can *unbind* it after `glVertexAttribPointer` is a given fact (and that I'm 110% percent sure of), otherwise you couldn't source different attributes from multiple buffers for a single draw call, could you?

Comment: The point when the `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...)` actually takes effect and when it's safe to change is a common point of confusion (and goes back to the fact that VBOs have been violently clubbed into the existing client array API driven by back-ward compatibility). A `glVertexAttribBuffer` function would have made more sense, though they recently cleared that up a bit (but those new functions mentioned by *t.niese*'s answer introduce other confusions).

Comment: @ChristianRau unbind is fully valid. I mean the `glDeleteBuffers`

Comment: I just tried this, and calling `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` before `glBindVertexArray(0);` resulted in nothing drawing to the screen. I can only unbind the VBO *after* the VAO has been unbound.

Comment: @MarkIngram You can unbind it freely *after* `glVertexAttribPointer` (I have to search for the *deleting* case though, I have to admit, but *unbinding has to work*, anything else is a driver bug or SO question). It's different for the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, of course, since that binding is directly stored in the VAO so should be kept bound if you want to do indexed rendering.

Comment: @t.niese I have removed the part about deleting for now, but I remember having searched for this fact and found it stated somewhere, otherwise I hadn't explicitly (and successfully) used it in my own code.

Comment: @ChristianRau you can re-include it. I found the corresponding section (5.1.2 Automatic Unbinding of Deleted Objects) `Attachments to unbound container objects, such as deletion of a buffer attached to a vertex array object which is not bound to the context, are not affected and continue to act as references on the deleted object, as described in the following section.` Could you please add this to the comment, sometimes i hate the specs ;)

Comment: @t.niese Thanks, but this sounds like it should at least be done *after* the `glBindVertexArray(0)`. Still I won't add this into the code comment (I already hated it to be two lines long ;)).

Comment: @ChristianRau i just ment the section number ;) ... and yes you could be right with the `glBindVertexArray(0)`. I'll definitiv do some further reading. I would like to remove my comments to keep this answer clean without this discussion if you don't mind, otherwise i'll keep it here.

Comment: @t.niese Well, it's just comments, I don't feel an urge to clean them. But if you want it's your decision, just try to keep the standard quote since I'm referencing it (and am too lazy to add it into my answer ;)).

Comment: @t.niese / Christian. Found out why I needed to unbind the VBO after the VAO. The VBO was being deleted after all the unbinding, which meant the memory was disappearing. On Mac / iOS this is OK, somehow the memory stays around, regardless, but on Windows it crashes. I've changed my code to preserve the VBO for lifetime of VAO, and now I can unbind the VBO before the VAO.

Comment: @MarkIngram As concluded by the comments, you can delete the VBO, but you need to unbind the *VAO* beforehand.

Comment: @ChristianRau when I tried that (deleting VBO after unbinding VAO) on Windows (using glew+glfw), I got `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error in `glDrawArrays`. I don't know if that is a separate problem or not.

Comment: Can you recommend equivalent for `glBindVertexArray` in OpenGL ES 2.0? https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/

Answer (score 4):

`glVertexAttribPointer` is something that does not really belong to the *Buffer* nor to the *Program* it is - let's say - the *glue* between them. (The functionality of this is splitten in Opengl 4.3 in different functions `VertexAttrib*Format`, `VertexAttribBinding` and `BindVertexBuffer` aviable through the [ARB_vertex_attrib_binding](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_attrib_binding.txt) )

But if you want to say that it is part of something i would say it is part of the `VAO` that stores the state of which Buffer objects are bound, which attribs are enabled and how the Buffer data has to be passed to the *Program*.

So it belongs to part where you setup your `VAO`s.

**EDIT**
Simple setup that illustrates the order:

1. creating/setup of `Buffer`s and creating programs
2. create `VAO` define which attribs are enabled, which buffers should be bound when the `VAO` is used and how that data is passed to the program (`glVertexAttribPointer`)

Answer (score 2):

The association of buffer, generic vertex attribute and shader attribute variable are quite subtle. `glVertexAttribPointer` establishes this association. See [OpenGL-Terminology](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/opengl-terminology-demystified/) for a detailed explanation.

Also, the link [OpenGL-VBO,shader,VAO](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/opengl-vbo-shader-vao/) shows a working example with the necessary sequence of API calls.

Answer (score 1):

`glVertexAttribPointer` has to be called (in most cases) when the appropriate (i.e. the one you want to use) VBO is bound. Then last parameter to it is offset in said buffer.

The last parameter is defined particularly nice in [the reference manual](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml):

> Specifies a offset of the first component of the first generic vertex
>   attribute in the array in the data store of the buffer currently bound
>   to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target. The initial value is 0.

Appropriate Vertex Pointer Bindings with VBO sources are stored inside VAO, and you should use that if possible.

Short example (excuse my pseudocode):

```
// Setup
CreateVAO(); BindVAO();
CreateVBO(); BindVBO();
VertexAttribPointer(/*id*/ 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, /*starting at offset*/ 0);

// We have specified Vertex attribute bound to location 0,
// with size of 3 floats, starting at offset 0 of VBO we've just created.        

//Draw
BindVAO();
Draw();
```

Comment: *"glVertexAttribPointer has to be called (in most cases) when the appropriate (i.e. the one you want to use) VBO is bound."* - Meh, rather the other way around. Binding of the VBO should be guided by when `glVertexAttribPointer` is called (and that is guided by either VAO setup time, or rendering time when not utilizing VAOs).

Comment: Well, a `glVertexAttribBuffer` function would be much more intuitive anyway, but that's OpenGL.

Comment: @ChristianRau IMHO that's pretty much the same, but I am not going to argue about semantics; also the community seems to agree with your answer more.

Comment: @ChristianRau We can only hope for 4.4/5.0 doing something better in that regard.